# Wait for page to load resources using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to access [snowdaypredictor.com](http://snowdaypredictor.com/) to get the chance of a snowday for a school project, the site does not automatically show the chance of a snowday as it has to load.  I have tried the below code, but it hasn't worked.  Is there anyway to wait before reading the data of a URL?

```
import urllib2
import time

url = 'http://snowdaypredictor.com%20%22SnowdayPredictor.com'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
time.sleep(10)
data = data.read()
```

Comment: It's not a matter of waiting some time before reading the page.  The value is hidden in the page somewhere, and being loaded in using javascript after the page has loaded.  I'm trying to see if I can figure out where the value is, and I'll let you know if I do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want actually isn't at the URL you think it is.  The page makes a *subsequent* request to another URL which returns the data about snowfall and snow day percentage, and then a script in the first page does the nice little counting up animation with that data.  This actually makes it extremely easy for you to get the data; here's an example:

https://api.snowdaypredictor.com/query/80424

Edit:

So I just tried this in python, and for some reason it was giving me an SSL error.  You can use `requests` instead of `urllib2` (You'll need to `pip install` it) to get by this, by using the verify=False flag. Here's some example code that gets the percentage for Breckenridge, CO and prints it.  You can safely ignore the warning (it seems that snowdaypredictor doesn't have its SSL certificates configured correctly:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://api.snowdaypredictor.com/query/80424', verify=False).json()['percent']
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:838: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
14
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Upvoted but I don't have the rep for it to display publicly.

Comment: In regards to the SSL Error: If Running on OSX, install ssl certificate authentication through bash, to do so:
1.  pip install certifi
2.  /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
     (Replace 3.6 with the appropriately installed version of python)